# trying to rescue bland chicken soup that is already quite thick

Tags: chicken, soup

how do you save a bland chicken soup that's already quite thick? i made a chicken/leek/rice soup last night that has a nice thick texture but it's bland -- i definitely didn't use enough salt in the cooking process. i'm wondering if i sweat another onion in some chicken fat and/or butter, add the soup, a little more water, and some vinegar, that might bring out some more depth, but i'm a little concerned that adding more water will just reinforce the blandness. thoughts?

Comment: If it's under-seasoned why not just add a bit more salt?

Comment: Personally, I would add about half a bottle of Sherry. :-)

Comment: Hot Sauce. Put Hot Sauce in your bowl and you're good ;)

Comment: It is generally helpful if you can give us the recipe you were working to so that we understand what is already in play. I appreciate soup can be less precise than many things, but an idea of your ingredients and process would be useful.

Comment: @GdD i def did add some more salt to counteract the bland, but was hoping to bring out more depth as well :)

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker sherry is a good idea, i need to replace mine..

Comment: @SnakeDoc excellent tip, i'm going to do that for next bowl

Comment: @Spagirl sure thing! i was riffing on this recipe https://smittenkitchen.com/2020/03/chicken-leek-and-rice-soup/ but i made a few changes based on what i had/what's worked well in the past, eg i used 4 leeks, 3 cloves of garlic, and a yellow onion, sweated them with schmaltz and butter. however, i subbed breasts for thighs and had less stock than called for, and i think that, plus covering it, were what made for a bland final result (whenever i've made this soup or a variation before, i've let it simmer uncover so it can reduce a bit/to prevent the steam buildup from diluting flavor).

Answer (score 2):

I always equate "depth" with "time".

The longer it simmers, the more depth it gains.

Adding anything you mentioned at the end may punch up the flavour, but I'd consider it to be 'top end' rather than 'depth'.

My first thought would be to drop it in a slow cooker & see how it is in 4-6 hours - with or without your added ingredients, though definitely half the salt you are considering adding if it really is under-salted. Salt during the process seems more effective than at the end. However, you can always lift it a little more at the end more easily than taking it out again if you over-do it ;)

I'd also consider 'cheating' with a **good** chicken or veg stock cube.

I'd be wary of vinegar, I'd be more inclined to butter &/or cream.

Comment: thanks for this! i think you're right about time. i ended up re-simmering it on the stove (i don't have a slow cooker) with some caramelized onions, white miso (unfortunately i didn't have any stock cubes) and some white wine vinegar and that seemed to fill out the flavor a bit more :)